# Tracking arm where some points disappear

Tags: tracking, motion-capture

I am trying my hand at some VFX with Blender, and I'm trying to make a digital arm move with my own. I drew lots of dots on my arm and hand with a dry erase marker and now I'm tracking them. Some of these tracks disappear when I rotate my arm, but there are always at least 8 active tracks. What can I do to get a successful solve from this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: i've had this same problem before, the track works until the points disappear and new ones are added, at which it goes berserk.  I hope someone can give a good answer.  +1, btw